# How to sort divs according to their dates or ids?

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I have these divs that are with dates as their ids.

```
<div id="20160106"></div>
<div id="20160105"></div>
```

and so on.

Is there a way to sort them from latest to earliest using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Use Sort.

```
var divID = [];
var sorted_arr=[];
$("div").each(function() {
    divID.push($(this).prop("id"));
     sorted_arr = divID.sort();
                 //divID.reverse();
})
 alert(sorted_arr);// For test
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwb3apw3/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#cont > div').sort(function(a, b){
  return toDate(a.id) > toDate(b.id);
}).appendTo($('#cont'));

function toDate(str){
  var dateStr = new Date(str.substring(0, 4), parseInt(str.substring(4, 6)) - 1, str.substring(6, 8));
  return dateStr.getTime();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont">
  <div id="20160106">20160106</div>
  <div id="20160105">20160105</div>
  <div id="20160206">20160206</div>
  <div id="20160405">20160405</div>
  <div id="20150502">20150502</div>
  <div id="20160106">20160106</div>
  <div id="20160106">20160106</div>
  <div id="20161105">20161105</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you converting the ids to date objects, would a simple string compare no work?